# Content Security Policy for Web Worker in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-worker, content-security-policy

In chrome everything is working as supposed - workers are loaded by script-src policy and processed by sandbox.js with it's own CSP. BUT in Firefox the things are different - it seems like it doesen't care on child-src, frame-src or CSP-header for sandbox.js(code for worker);

So my CSP header is this :

`default-src 'self';`

and header for sandbox.js is

`default-src 'none'; script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';`

and for some reason when I do

`new Worker('/sandbox.js')`
it says

`Content Security Policy: Page parametrs blocked resource download in self("default-src 'self'").
Call to eval() or related function blocked by CSP.
Error: call to eval() blocked by CSP`

is there any way to allow unsafe-eval in a webworker for firefox? I just need those for my templates and running it in a sandbox is a good idea, imho.

Comment: it seems like it is a browser bug or not yet implemented.
Posted this issue to [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1200566)

Comment: Maybe nonce-attr for webworker can help, but the thing is that nonce must be in DOM and there is no info about how to create Web Worker with nonce attribute or set it in header for the file